# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.initObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, jackson, client

I am trying to open a WebSocket in Spring Client. I take inspiration from https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client

For that, I have build this function:

```
public static void connectWebSocket(){
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler);

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Don't close immediately.
    }
```

When I try to call the function `connectWebSocket`, I have an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.initObjectMapper(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:92) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

In my pom.xml, I have:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried to change my dependencies with diferent version of `RELEASE`. I also add :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` is normally imported from `spring-messaging`.

I do not understand the meaning of my error, can somebody halp me for that?